# floating a moving div inside another div, overflow hidden, css fix?

Tags: css

I have a div of an aeroplane inside parent div with `overflow: hidden`, so it looks as though the aeroplane div is flying from under an element on the page and dragging a banner with it.

See my diagram here:

[image: Diagram]

The css code I have already is:

```
#plane{
width: 195px;
background-image: url(images/plane.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 444px;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
#plane-holder {
height: 569px;
width: 960px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 2200;
display: inherit;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Netball Plane</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><div id="topbar"><img src="images/contact-us-bar.gif" width="960" height="45" /></div>
</div>
<div id="content"><div id="mainbody"><div id="menubar"><div id="logo"><img     src="images/logo.gif" width="284" height="103" /></div>
<div class="menu">
Menu to go here
</div>
</div>
</div><div id="hero"><div id="information-that"><h1>Hello welcome to the site</h1>
<p></p><p>Some more text here.</p>
<p><img src="images/netball.png" alt="Rollover the netball for more information"     width="187" height="46" border="0" /></p>
</div>
</div><div id="hero-shadow"></div><script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
    var iCounter = 1;
    var iMaxCounter = 4;

        $( '#plane' ).animate({ 
            top: "-=450px",
            left: "+=857px"
        }, 30000, function(){
        }       
        ); 
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
      fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
      after:onAfter
    });

});
        </script>
<div id="plane-holder"><div id="plane"></div>
</div><div id="base-content"><div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but this is displaying as a block pushing the other elements below these divs down the page.

Do you know of a way to fix this so the plane and it's containing div is floating above my site? I've tried setting the z-index, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you should use position `relative+absolute` setting `position: relative` on the `container` and `absolute` (with a defined z-index) for the `#plane`

place the `#plane` with `top/left/right/bottom` properties

- at the begin you have `bottom : -<somepixels>, left : 0`
- at the end you have `top : 0, right : 0`

Doing so other elements won't be affected by the presence of the plane, staying where you placed them

Use also `pointer-events: none` if you want to allow `click/hover` events behind the plane: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events (unfortunately it's not supported by `IE<=8`although some js workarounds have been published, e.g. by Lea Verou)

Comment: Thank you! That almost works, but it makes the content underneath the two divs not clickable :( Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks @F. Calderan - The pointer events link doesn't seem to be much use to me as it talks about using SVG graphics and I'm not using them.

I've added my HTML above if that helps?

Thank you again fro all your help! :)

Comment: I now have a large gap below the plane content. I'm confused :/